# Cyclical Ketogenic Diet : type of fats + how many grams of carbs per day

Tags: diet, weight-loss, fat, carbohydrate, ketogenic-diet

I am going to shift to a new diet : **[The Cyclical Ketogenic Diet](http://www.ketodietplan.com/cyclical-ketogenic-diet/)**.

I read and understood in general what is it about but i have two questions:

- When they say High fat intake, is it a specific type of fat: ***saturated / trans / polyunsaturated / mononunsaturated*** , or **any** of these in general?
- The diet mentions days of **low carbs** and days of **high carbs**: how many grams of carbs per kg/pound of body weight is **low carbs** ? **high carbs** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who wants to follow this diet and has similar questions, here are the answers i found:

```
Q1: When they say High fat intake, is it a specific type of fat: saturated / trans
    / polyunsaturated / mononunsaturated , or any of these in general?
```

**Answer:**

> Although all fats are allowed, foods with healthy fat are preferred, and will ultimately keep you feeling good as well. Foods like tuna, salmon, shellfish, bacon and other fatty meats are appropriate choices, but watch for hidden carbohydrates that might be present in sausages and hot dogs. According to Epilepsy.com, foods such as butter, heavy whipping cream and mayonnaise, and oils like canola and olive oil are also good sources of fats appropriate to the cyclical ketogenic diet.

(**source** : [link](http://www.livestrong.com/article/227032-food-list-cyclical-ketogenic-diet/)).
PS: What they mean by healthy fat is **poly and mono unsaturated fat**.

```
Q2: The diet mentions days of low carbs and days of high carbs: how many grams of carbs 
    per kg/pound of body weight is low carbs ? high carbs ?
```

**Answer:**

> **How Many Carbs Is Low-Carb?**
>
> In order to become a 'fat-burner', you should consume around 60 grams or less of net carbohydrate per day (total carbs minus fiber). However, in order to determine just how many carbs you personally should be consuming, a little trial and error is necessary.
>
> The general rule is this:
>
> Eat the smallest amount of carbs it takes to allow maximum output in the gym.
>
> This will vary from person to person. Please bear in mind that fat will become your main source of energy and large quantities of carbs are unnecessary.
>
> If you are unsure, try beginning at 30 grams and adjust as necessary.

(**source** : [link](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/cyclical_ketogenic_diet.htm))